# Search List<entity> for Records with matching value for a Class Property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, search, webforms

I have created a Model class in my ASP.Net Forms application called `Years_Of_Service`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PROJECT.Models.Default
{
    public class Years_Of_Service
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string FiscalYear
        {
            get
            {
                return Year + "-" + (Year + 1);
            }
        }
        public decimal ServiceCredited { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public string CoveredEmployer { get; set; }


        public string TotalService { get; set; }
        public string PurchasedorReinstatedService { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am successfully querying my database and returning appropriate values within this Model class via my Custom Control, however in some select cases I am returned records which have the same [Year] value:

[image: Grid]

What I need to do now is loop through each entity in my list, and if 2 or more entities have a matching value for [Year], merge them together and change the value of [Covered Employer] to "Multiple Employers".

A simple foreach loop will take me through each entity, but I am at a loss as to how I would then do a sub-search of every OTHER entity for a matching [Year] value and combine the 2. Can anyone point me in the right direction for how this can best be accomplished?

This is my Custom Control page's code I have so far:

```
public partial class YearsOfService : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public List<Years_Of_Service> lyos { get; set; }
    public Years_Of_Service y_o_s { get; set; }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            ApplyData();
        }
    }

    private void ApplyData()
    {

        foreach (Years_Of_Service yearsOfService in lyos)
        {
            // Search [lyos] for records with same [Year] value (ex. "2009-2010")
            // If found, Add the [Service] & [Salary] Values together under one [Year] record.
            // Change the newly "merged" record to say "Multiple Employers" for [CoveredEmployer]
        }

        salaryGridView.DataSource = lyos;
        salaryGridView.DataBind();

        if (y_o_s.TotalService.ToString() != null)
        {
            creditSalLabel.Text = y_o_s.TotalService.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            creditSalLabel.Text = String.Empty;
        }

        if (y_o_s.PurchasedorReinstatedService.ToString() != null)
        {
            purchaseCreditLabel.Text = y_o_s.PurchasedorReinstatedService.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            purchaseCreditLabel.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Food for thought: `if (y_o_s.TotalService.ToString() != null)` not good.

Comment: Any suggestions for better method (now, and in the future)?

Comment: Remember the thumb rule, when you use a method/property, understand its actual usage. Now, consider `ToString()`, it always returns a string. But if your object is null, then that object ToString is an error. That said, checking `if(y_o_s.TotalService != null)` is the proper way.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the insight. I think I originally had that in there that way simply because I was trying to figure out where/why I was getting a `NullReferenceException` on another issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [group by approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716793(v=vs.100).aspx).

should be something like:

```
var groupedByYearLyos = lyos.GroupBy(x => x.Year)
    .Select(x => new Years_Of_Service() 
        { 
            CoveredEmployer = x.Count() > 1 ? "Multiple Employers" : x.First().CoveredEmployer,
            Year = x.Key,
            Salary = x.Sum(y => y.Salary)
             //and etc 
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: `CoveredEmployer` should not be changed to `"Multiple Employers"` if group count = 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vladimirs. I think this is exactly the type of thing I was looking for! Now I just need to finish up my coding for the current Years value (weird calculations that are done separate). Joys of leaving the 400 behind and going into the future!